# Year also showing up before reference in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am new to using BibTeX. Although I have been using LaTeX for quite some time, I used to write all my references manually, lol!
My preamble is

```
\documentclass[10pt,letter]{article}  
\usepackage{fullpage}  
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{parskip}  
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}  
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,  
            linkcolor = blue,  
            urlcolor  = blue,  
            citecolor = blue,  
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}  
\usepackage[round]{natbib}  
\let\cite\citep  

\renewenvironment{abstract}  
  {{\bfseries\noindent{\large\abstractname}\par\nobreak}}  
  {}  

\renewenvironment{quote}  
  {\begin{tabular}{|p{13cm}}}  
  {\end{tabular}}  

\usepackage{authblk}  
\makeatletter  
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\rlap{\textsuperscript{\normalfont#1}}}  
\renewcommand\Authsep{,~\,}  
\renewcommand\Authands{,~\,and }  
\makeatother  

.....other \usepackages...

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
```

I copied this from an online source and it seems to work well in terms of citing the references (`\citet{}`) and making the bibliography. Only some of the elements in the bibliography is weird as I show below:

```
\begin{document}  
\title{}  
.....  
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  
\bibliography{biblio}  
\end{document}
```

`biblio` is a bibtex file (.bib) containing the references.

If I use

```
@Misc{bbc2016,
  url={http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-37536348},
  note = {Accessed 2017-03-01},
  title = {{India ratifies Paris climate agreement}},
 journal={{BBC News}},
  author = {{BBC News}},
  year = {2016},
}
```

I get

```
2016 BBC News. India ratifies Paris climate agreement. http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-
37536348, 2016. Accessed 2017-03-01.
```

I have tried changing the environment to "article" but it does not help. Every time I save the BibTeX file (`biblio.bib`) and do `\bibliography{biblio}`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with a current MiKTeX 2.9 I can compile the following MWE (I used your code and added the bib file with package `filecontents` to the MWE) with the result you want.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Misc{bbc2016,
  url={http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-37536348},
  note = {Accessed 2017-03-01},
  title = {{India ratifies Paris climate agreement}},
 journal={{BBC News}},
  author = {{BBC News}},
  year = {2016},
}
@article{bbc2017,
  url={http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-37536348},
  note = {Accessed 2017-03-01},
  title = {{India ratifies Paris climate agreement}},
 journal={{BBC News}},
  author = {{BBC News}},
  year = {2017},
}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{feynman,
  title     = {Very High-Energy Collisions of Hadrons},
  author    = {Richard P. Feynman},
  journal   = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume    = {23},
  issue     = {24},
  pages     = {1415--1417},
  year      = {1969},
  month     = {Dec},
  doi       = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  url       = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
}
\end{filecontents}


\listfiles % only to get a list of used packages and version numbers
\documentclass[10pt,letter]{article}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 

\usepackage{fullpage}  
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{parskip}  
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{authblk}  
\usepackage[round]{natbib}  
\let\cite\citep  

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}  
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,  
            linkcolor = blue,  
            urlcolor  = blue,  
            citecolor = blue,  
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}  


\renewenvironment{abstract}  
  {{\bfseries\noindent{\large\abstractname}\par\nobreak}}  
  {}  

\renewenvironment{quote}  
  {\begin{tabular}{|p{13cm}}}  
  {\end{tabular}}  


\makeatletter  
\renewcommand\AB@authnote[1]{\rlap{\textsuperscript{\normalfont#1}}}  
\renewcommand\Authsep{,~\,}  
\renewcommand\Authands{,~\,and }  
\makeatother  


\begin{document}  
\title{test}

test \citet{bbc2016} test \citet{bbc2017} test\citet{adams} test
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use bib file created with filecontents 
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image: resulting bibliography]

Command `\listfiles` shows me the following used packages and version numbers.  Please copy my MWE, compile it on your computer and compare my list with yours (see at the end of the log file for this list):

```
 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2017/06/29 3.12 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
 ngerman.ldf    2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
 english.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
fullpage.sty    1999/02/23 1.1 (PWD)
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
titlesec.sty    2016/03/21 v2.10.2 Sectioning titles
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
 authblk.sty    2001/02/27 1.3 (PWD)
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
  364889.out
  364889.out
  364889.bbl
 ***********
```